# Routine for Bulk deletion of users in toad

Tags: toad, bulk-delete

Can anyone help me with the routine for the bulk deletion of users based on any criteria in the toad database.

Comment: Toad isn't a database. Toad is a tool for accessing the database. What database are you using? There are many flavors of Toad.

Comment: The database used is SQL.

Comment: Can anyone also explain what is a routine regarding database?

Comment: SQL is not a database. I don't know the answer to your question one way or the other, but it would help others if they know which database you're connecting to. There are many different versions of Toad for different databases, most of which support SQL. Is this Oracle, MySQL, etc.? You also haven't specified what kind of criteria you're trying to search for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Oracle database this example will delete all users having a username starting with DELETEMEUSER. You can write a query to fetch users matching your criteria and delete using dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1
   IS
      SELECT username
        FROM all_users
       WHERE username LIKE 'DELETEMEUSER%';
BEGIN
   FOR c1_rec IN c1
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP USER ' || c1_rec.username || ' CASCADE';
   END LOOP;
END;
```